# How to export the minimum values to a .csv file?

Tags: export

I would like to export only the minimum values (here I’m finding the minimum Ra for each R0 and these minimum values are indicated in yellow cells) to a .csv file as shown below the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
k[R0_, m_] := R0/m;
Ra[Q_, R0_, m_] := Q (R0/m)
data = Table[{Q, R0, m, k[R0, m], Ra[Q, R0, m]}, {Q, 1, 3, 1}, {R0, 1,
     1.15, 0.05}, {m, {3.83171, 7.01559, 10.1735, 13.3237, 16.4706, 
     19.6159}}];
FormatCells[table_] := 
 With[{minPosition = Ordering[table, 1, Last[#1] < Last[#2] &]}, 
  MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Yellow] &, 
   TableForm[{#}, TableDirections -> Row, 
      TableHeadings -> {None, {"Q", "R0", "m", "k", "Ra"}}, 
      TableSpacing -> {.8, .8}] & /@ table, minPosition]]
FormatTable[table_] := Grid[FormatCells /@ table, Dividers -> All]
FormatTable[data[[1]]]
Export["Min Ra for R0=1,1.05,1.1,1.15.csv", data]
```

[image]

I tried using the export command, but that’s not how I want the output to look like. Is it possible to export the data as shown in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MinimalBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinimalBy.html) to get the correct cells. Then [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html).

```
table = First@MinimalBy[#, Last] & /@ First@data;

Export["data.csv", table, TableHeadings -> {"Q", "R0", "m", "k", "Ra"}]
```

Comment: How can I export the data for different values of Q. When I change the code to FormatTable[data[[2]]], (which gives the minimum Ra for Q=2), the data in the .csv file still shows the minimum Ra for Q=0. @Domen

Comment: Replace ``First@data`` in my code with ``data[[2]]``.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow values are

```
minData = data[[1, All, 6]]
```

Add column headers to the export

```
Export["minData.csv", minData // Prepend[{"Q", "R0", "m", "k", "Ra"}]]
```

Comment: The code will give an error because it will always export the last cell values, even if they're not minimum. @Rohit Namjoshi

Comment: @Math_student True, you have to identify the minimum to isolate the correct element of `data` to export as shown by @Domen.